# Update random values to selected columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I want to update selected column values with random number in single query. As you can see the attached screenshot, I want to update random values in column: meta_value

[image: screenshot of database query I applied]

Comment: Even with the image, your question is quite unclear.  I would recommend that you provide sample data and desired results as a *text table* in the question.  Also, explain what *you* mean by "random values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this query to generate and update random number between 0-99:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=FLOOR(RAND()*100) WHERE meta_key='trx_addons_post_views_count';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use `RAND()`. Say you want a number between 0 and 9999, you can do:

```
update mytable set meta_value = floor(rand() * 10000)
```

Comment: I want to update only values of "meta_value" column against values in meta_key="trx_addons_post_views_count" 


What command should be run to make my condition truly followed ?

Comment: @AnkushKumar: just add a `where` clause to the query: `update mytable set meta_value = floor(rand() * 10000) where meta_key = 'trx_addons_post_views_count'`